# Al intentar obtener el valor del atributo data-* de un datalist, el valor retornado siempre es null

Tags: javascript, html, html5-datalist

Tengo un formulario con un `datalist`. Cada `option` tiene un valor para mostrarle al usuario y un atributo `data-val` que es el que quiero obtener para meter en la base de datos.

He visto varios ejemplos de cómo obtener el contenido de los atributos `data-*` del elemento seleccionado pero no consigo que me funcione ninguno. Siempre recibo un `null`. Pongo el código a ver si me pueden ayudar e indicarme qué estoy haciendo mal:

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" id="cliente" list="clientes" onChange="getVal()">
   <datalist id="clientes">
      <option value="Menganito" data-val="1"></option>
      <option value="Fulanito" data-val="2"></option>
      <option value="Zulanita" data-val="3"></option>
   </datalist>
</form>

<script>
   function getVal() {
      const clientesel = document.getElementById("cliente");
      var valor = clientesel.getAttribute("data-val");
      alert (valor);  //Siempre devuelve un null
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucede que estás intentando obtener el *data-val* en el elemento `input`, y allí existen los atributos *type*, *id*, *list* y *onChange*. Esto es comprobable con la función [`getAttributeNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNames):

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" id="cliente" list="clientes" onChange="getVal()">
   <datalist id="clientes">
      <option value="Menganito" data-val="1"></option>
      <option value="Fulanito" data-val="2"></option>
      <option value="Zulanita" data-val="3"></option>
   </datalist>
</form>

<script>
   function getVal() {
      const clientesel = document.getElementById("cliente");
      alert(clientesel.getAttributeNames());
}
</script>
```

Ya que los `datalist` no cuentan con la propiedad `selectedIndex`, se podría hacer lo siguiente:

1. Obtener el `input`;
2. obtener el `datalist`;
3. obtener la opción seleccionada buscando en el `datalist` el valor ingresado en el `input`, con [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector);
4. obtener el atributo `data-*` de la opción seleccionada con [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute),
5. o con [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="cliente" list="clientes" onChange="getVal()">
  <datalist id="clientes">
      <option value="Menganito" data-val="1"></option>
      <option value="Fulanito" data-val="2"></option>
      <option value="Zulanita" data-val="3"></option>
   </datalist>
</form>

<script>
  function getVal() {
    let elemento_input = document.getElementById('cliente'); //1
    let elemento_datalist = document.getElementById('clientes'); //2
    let op_seleccionada = elemento_datalist.querySelector(`[value="${elemento_input.value}"]`); //3
    let seleccion = op_seleccionada.getAttribute('data-val'); //4
    let seleccion_con_dataset = op_seleccionada.dataset.val; //5
    alert(seleccion);
    alert(seleccion_con_dataset);
  }
</script>
```

<sub>Código adaptado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63134338) de [@nimey sara thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3716927) en el sitio en inglés.</sub>

> Se podría mejorar aún más el código, como por ejemplo evitando usar `onChange` y usar el evento [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) de JS. Como se menciona en [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these):
>
> > Puedes encontrar atributos HTML equivalentes para muchas de las propiedades de los manejadores de eventos; sin embargo, no deberías usarlos - se consideran una mala práctica.
>
> Incluso se podrían utilizar otros eventos... Pero es cuestión de investigar :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por lo detallado de la respuesta. No conocía el .getAttributeNames(). Lo veo muy útil para casos como este. Por último le echaré un ojo a lo de usar los eventos de JS en lugar de los de HTML. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

probablemente esto es lo que estas buscando espero te sirva, usando `javascript` y `Jquery`

```js
function getVal(){
  //Obtener valor del input
   var val=$('#cliente').val();
   alert(val)
   //Buscar elemento por su valor y extraer el data
   var clienteValue =  $('#clientes').find(`option[value="${val}"]`).data("val")
   alert(clienteValue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <input type="text" id="cliente" list="clientes" onInput="getVal()">
   <datalist id="clientes">
      <option value="Menganito" data-val="1"></option>
      <option value="Fulanito" data-val="2"></option>
      <option value="Zulanita" data-val="3"></option>
   </datalist>
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, funciona perfectamente. Por ahora voy a aplicar la otra opción que me han dado porque aún no he mirado nada de Jquery pero la tendré presente para el futuro. Un saludo.